# How to find subdirectories of only two levels deep?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, dir

I got a script that lists all subdirectories in a folder and put them in a file:

```
dir "\\test\e$\1" /a:d /s /b | sort>"C:\folders.txt
```

effect looks like this:

```
\\test\e$\1
\\test\e$\1\target1
\\test\e$\1\target1\in
\\test\e$\1\target1\out
\\test\e$\1\target2
\\test\e$\1\target2\in
\\test\e$\1\target2\out
\\test\e$\1\target3
\\test\e$\1\target3\in
\\test\e$\1\target3\out
\\test\e$\2
\\test\e$\2\target1
\\test\e$\2\target1\in
\\test\e$\2\target1\out
\\test\e$\2\target2
\\test\e$\2\target2\in
\\test\e$\2\target2\out
\\test\e$\2\random_folder_without_in_subfolder
```

what I really need:

```
\\test\e$\1\target1
\\test\e$\1\target2
\\test\e$\1\target3
\\test\e$\2\target1
\\test\e$\2\target2
```

even better (if possible) in this form (separator: "**|:**"):

```
\\test\e$\1\target1|:\\test\e$\1\target2|:\\test\e$\1\target3|:\\test\e$\2\target1|:\\test\e$\2\target2
```

Comment: `for /F "usebackq tokens=1-5* delims=\" %G in ("[…\]folders.txt") do @echo %G %K` could be your starting point (replace `[…\]` with actual path to your file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s /b /ad "%sourcedir%" '
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=3,4delims=\" %%d IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%e"=="" (ECHO(%%a) ELSE GOTO secondway
)

:secondway
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion 
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "longline="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s /b /ad "%sourcedir%" '
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=3,4delims=\" %%d IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%e"=="" (
  SET "longline=!longline!|:%%a"
 ) ELSE GOTO done2
)

:done2
SET "longline=!longline:~2!"
SET longline
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set longline') DO ECHO %%b
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

May have problems with directorynames containing characters that have a special meaning to `cmd`.

Comment: I hoped it would be somewhat cleaner :) I know where to look for, thanks.