# get files list in a specific subfolder

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am trying with no success to get a list of files in a .csv (and relative properties) recursevely just in one subfolders.
This is my situation:

```
Root
|
| - Folder 1
|   | - xxxxxx
|   | - yyyyyyy
|   | - INTERESTED_FOLDER  (that contains files requested)
|
| - ...
|
| - Folder n:
    | - xxxxxx
    | - yyyyyy
    | - INTERESTED_FOLDER (that contains files requested)
```

Examples I found on web talk about getting all files names in ALL subdirectories, when I'd need to search just in one but iterate for all root folders 1-n.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936340/how-to-find-subdirectories-of-only-two-levels-deep/33941289#33941289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab all the `INTERESTED_FOLDERs` in one go using the `-Include` parameter, then get the contents of all of them.

If you use Where-Object then PowerShell retrieves all items then filters them, which takes longer and may be significant if you have a lot of items (you can assess the difference by including your code block in a `Measure-Object` statement). Always try and use the native provider's filtering capabilities as this will reduce execution time. If you are using PowerShell v3 or above there are additional arguments for files or folders available in Get-ChildItem:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory -Include 'INTERESTED_FOLDER','INTERESTED_FOLDER1' |
Foreach-Object {Get-ChildItem $_ -File} |
Export-Csv -Path $OutPutFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great but I noticed another and last thing I need: to get ONLY the NEWEST file between those two interested folders. I am already reading the attr. with `Select-Object name, LastWriteTime` but of course it will return the newest for BOTH folders, so I will have 2 files. I think the script must be revised for doing that.

Comment: Do you mean that for all instances of INTERESTED_FOLDERn you need to find the single most recent file in those folders?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If folder A contains subfolder B and C (my interested) and both B and C contains a .doc (for instance), I need to get the single most recent .doc between B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to first retrieve all Folders `1-n`, than you call it again and filter the `INTERESTED_FOLDER` and finally call it another time to retrieve all items within that and export the csv:

```
Get-ChildItem | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    Get-ChildItem -Filter 'INTERESTED_FOLDER' | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
            Export-Csv -Path c:\content.csv
```

Comment: That's working well, thanks.What about if interested folders are more than 1?

Comment: I think you have to do something like this: `Get-ChildItem  | ? { $_.Name -match '^INTERESTED_FOLDER1$|^INTERESTED_FOLDER2$'}`